# upstart script not working for a new service

Tags: upstart

I have a /etc/init.d/some-file script which starts a service.

I want that to be a part of upstart, meaning when i do a kill -9 on the process of the service, the service should auto start.

I created a file in /etc/init/some-file.conf

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

exec /etc/init.d/some-file start
```

Once i created this file i ran the below command to reload the configuration changes.

```
initctl reload-configuration
```

But the service does not start up when i kill the process.

Am i missing some concept here or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In the script,

```
exec /etc/init.d/some-file start
```

should be the path to the **executable or binary** that this upstart should start and not itself.

So change this to the name of the process like

```
exec /usr/bin/<NameOfProcess>
```

**EDIT:**

After adding changes to the conf file run the below command.

```
$ sudo initctl start some-file
```

where `some-file` is the name of your upstart job.

Also to verify that your upstart job is running, run the below comand

```
$ initctl list
```

Comment: I added the some-file to /usr/local/bin. No positive results

Comment: What type of file is `some-file` ? A binary or shell script ?

Comment: It is shell script. initctl list shows some-file. The service starts when i do inictl start some-file. But when i do kill -9 <pid of some-file> , the service does not start up automatically

Comment: Shell scripts would spawn if killed using upstart because `respawn`  will exec only when the associated process terminates abnormally without return zero. So in your case when you kill the process associated with shell script you are terminating the `/bin/sh` process and not the shell script.

Comment: you have a point. Any suggestions on what i can do on such scenarios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72132/discussion-between-chetan-and-santosh-a).